# call a non extension method defined inside non static class from Main() c#

Tags: c#

I tried calling Extension method defined under static class from Main(), It worked.
Now I want to use this in my application, to do so I need make the Extension method as a static method(Because I don' t have static classes defined in my application) and call It from Main().

Here what I' m trying:

```
public class Get 
{  
     public static void CopyTo(Stream input, Stream output) //Method
       {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];  
       int read;
       while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
       {
       output.Write (buffer, 0, read);
       }
       }  
 public static void Main ()
    {
              ////I' m just mentioning a small part of my code
              ////Please ignore about the variables(url, baseURL,authenticatestr...) those are not declared here, they have been declared at some other part in the code
            /////Here in the main method I have a call to the above method

       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
       request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (baseURL + uri);
       request.Headers.Add ("Authn", authenticateStr);
       request.Accept = "";
       request.Method = "GET";
       webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream("1" , FileMode.Create)) {
           webResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);///Here I need to call my method                                                                      
           outfile.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
                }
```

But this is still trying to call the .NetFramework CopyTo() method.  How do I make a call to the defined method int the code?
Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I make a call to the defined method int the code?

Just don't call it *on* a stream (which makes it look like an instance method). Call it as a normal static method, with two arguments corresponding to the two parameters:

```
CopyTo(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), ms);
```

Non-extension static methods can never be called on an instance. You can use just the simple name, or qualify it with the type name (`Get.CopyTo(...)`).

It's not clear why you want to use this at all if you're using .NET 4+ where `CopyTo` is supported though.

Comment: I' m using .Net 3.5 which is the supported higher version by my application, So I tried this.

Comment: @user2314238: If you're only using .NET 3.5, how do you explain your statement that "this is still trying to call the .NetFramework CopyTo() method"? That method doesn't exist in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Error says..'System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for 'CopyTo' and no extension method 'CopyTo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.Stream' could be found .

Comment: @user2314238: Okay, so it's not so much that it's "trying to call the framework CopyTo method" - it's that it's trying to call *any* CopyTo method, and that doesn't exist in .NET 3.5.

Comment: I think the question was how to make the extension method work, hence I have added this as a separate answer. Note that M.K wanted to use his own code to copy the stream in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you wanted to create an extension method which copies a stream into another one. To define an extension method, use

```
public static class myExtensions
{
     public static void myCopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)
     {
        // your code goes here
     }
}
```

Then you can call it the following way:

```
webResponse.GetResponseStream().myCopyTo(ms);
```

**Notes:**

- The **class** which contains the extension methods must be **static** and it must be a top-level class.
- The **extension method** must be static as well, it must contain the keyword **`this`** as 1st parameter. This parameter denotes the type of the class which you want to extend.
- I have renamed your method to avoid conflicts with the existing .NET framework's `CopyTo` method

I hope that helps. Please let me know if you need any additional hints.